# Combining various rows in a table based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

need some help to construct a PostgreSQL query. I am trying to combine various rows in a Postgres table based on a certain condition.

Here's what the table looks like

| Roll_No | Role | Address Type | Address Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0538 | Home | Address Line 1 | 123 Main Street |
| 0538 | Home | Address Line 2 | London |
| 0538 | Home | Address Line 3 | Rogers Street |
| 0538 | Home | Address Line 4 | United Kingdom |
| 0538 | Office | Address Line 1 | Adam Land |
| 0538 | Office | Address Line 2 | Valley Forge PA 19482 |
| 0538 | Office | Address Line 3 | U.S.A |
| 0738 | School | Address Line 1 | Rogers Street |
| 0738 | School | Address Line 2 | London |
| 0738 | School | Address Line 3 | Holland Lane |
| 0738 | School | Address Line 4 | United Kingdom |

I want to concatenate all address values of a specific role (eg. home, school, office) into one column. Address type can contain values like Address Line 1 to 8. Here, Home has Address Line 1 to 4 whereas office has Address Line 1 to 3.

| Roll_No | Role | Address Type | Address Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0538 | Home | Home Address | 123 Main Street, London, Rogers Street, United Kingdom |
| 0538 | Office | Office Address | Adam Land, Valley Forge PA 19482, U.S.A |
| 0738 | School | School Address | Rogers Street, London, Holland Lane, United Kingdom |

Comment: Which version of postgresql you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ARRAY_AGG()` inside `ARRAY_TO_STRING()` but with **caution**. Because generally, `SQL` tables are `unordered` sets. Hence explicitly mentioning `ORDER BY` inside `array_agg()` is very very important.

**Code:**

```
SELECT 
    Roll_No, 
    role,
    role || ' address' AS address_type, 
    array_to_string(array_agg(addressvalue ORDER BY roll_no, role, addresstype), ', ') as address_value
FROM t
GROUP BY Roll_No, role
ORDER BY roll_no, role, address_value
```

Look at the *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=da7c979e16d080fa37d8491a3d64b06e)*. Take a look how results vary with and without `ORDER BY` inside `array_agg()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **array_agg()** function for combining column value with comma. Here ORDER BY clause isn't used because address line 4 wouldn't come before address line 1. **Extra** ORDER BY clause can degrade query performance for a **large** data sets

```
-- PostgreSQL
SELECT roll_no, role
     , role || ' Address' address_type
     , array_to_string(array_agg(address_value), ', ') address_value  
FROM test
GROUP BY roll_no, role
ORDER BY roll_no, role;
```

Please check this **url** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e46cf351452a2715258b69afeea5c742

If **ORDER BY** must needed inside array_agg() function then use the below query

```
-- after applying order by inside array_agg()
SELECT roll_no, role
     , role || ' Address' address_type
     , array_to_string(array_agg(address_value order by address_type), ', ') address_value  
FROM test
GROUP BY roll_no, role
ORDER BY roll_no, role;
```

Please check the **url** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c196a9a2ca71bd886e4750b935d23040

If **same** address stored for multiple address **line** of a particular role for specific roll_no then **DISTINCT** keyword will use inside array_agg().

```
-- after applying distinct inside array_agg()
SELECT roll_no, role
     , role || ' Address' address_type
     , array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT address_value), ', ') address_value  
FROM test
GROUP BY roll_no, role
ORDER BY roll_no, role;
```

Please check this **url** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e4f0de7c37e003133e2539149db245f8

Comment: If the order changes, then address will also change right? Look at office address in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=95ad863e028d29aee22a179db9571236

Comment: In this example ORDER BY isn't needed inside array_agg function. Because address line 4 may not come before address line 1 in this table. So extra order by degrade query performance. @Arun

Comment: I see that both you and Arun use a combination of `array_agg` and `array_to_string` in your answers. Can you explain what the benefit is of using this instead of a simple `string_agg`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner string_agg isn't supported at lower version of postgresql.